# How can I stop the polling function for that particular API that runs a background job?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have used this common polling function for running background jobs.

```
export const poll = ({
  fn = () => {},
  validate = (result) => !!result,
  interval = 1000,
  maxAttempts = 15,
}) => {
  let attempts = 1;
  // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
  const executePoll = async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const result = await fn();
      attempts += 1;

      if (validate(result)) {
        return resolve(result);
      } else if (maxAttempts && attempts > maxAttempts) { // eslint-disable-line no-else-return
        return reject(new Error('Exceeded max attempts'));
      } else {
        setTimeout(executePoll, interval, resolve, reject);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setTimeout(executePoll, interval, resolve, reject);
    }
  };

  return new Promise(executePoll);
};
```

I have called this function on click of a button for running polling:

```
poll({
          fn: () =>  some API call ex. api.get(url),
          validate: (res) => !res?.data?.lesson_id,
          interval: 5000,
          maxAttempts: 30,
        })
```

The issue is that after running the above function in the UI, I am showing a delete icon. On clicking that delete icon, I am removing the element for which the above background job is running.

So I want to stop the above polling function after successful deletion.

Note: I have the delete function on that same page so I have control over delete when it is successful.

What can I change in my common polling function?

Answer (score 0):

Have your `poll` function also accept an object or callback that will evaluate to the cancel state or not.  You can use the return value of `setTimeout` to call the `clearTimeout` to cancel the behavior.  You also want to clear that timeout for each new timer.  You can also have it return a function that you can call.

```
const continueControl = {
   continue: true
}

poll({
    fn: () =>  some API call ex. api.get(url),
    validate: (res) => !res?.data?.lesson_id,
    interval: 5000,
    maxAttempts: 30,
    continueControl
})
```

```
export const poll = ({
  fn = () => {},
  validate = (result) => !!result,
  interval = 1000,
  maxAttempts = 15,
  continueControl = { continue: true }
}) => {
  let attempts = 1;
  let timeoutId = null;
 
  // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
  const executePoll = async (resolve, reject) => {
    if (!continueControl.continue) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      return reject(new Error('Reject or resolve as you like'));
    }

    try {
      const result = await fn();
      attempts += 1;

      if (validate(result)) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        return resolve(result);
      } else if (maxAttempts && attempts > maxAttempts) { // eslint-disable-line no-else-return
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        return reject(new Error('Exceeded max attempts'));
      } else {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(executePoll, interval, resolve, reject);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      timeoutId = setTimeout(executePoll, interval, resolve, reject);
    }
  };

  const stopPolling = () => {
     clearTimeout(timeoutId);
     continueControl.continue = false;
  }

  return { promise: new Promise(executePoll), stopPolling};
};
```

```
const {promise, stopPolling} = poll( .... )

// Set this whenever you have your delete occur
continueControl.continue = false

// or call

stopPolling();
```

Comment: One question I am getting const { stopPolling } = poll(...) in another button event how i can get it globally so I can use it in the delete function as well?